# Asound finds soundcard, but pavucontrol doesn't

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

After installing nix and rebooting, I am facing a curious bug: My soundcard was found (I think), but my system only shows a dummy output.
Before that sound had worked just fine.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards                                                                 
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xa1518000 irq 150
```

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
$ aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav 
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

But `pavucontrol` only shows the dummy output and there is no sound.

OS: Kubuntu 19.04

Comment: Please specify your OS/release.  Also if it's a bug (thus reported), please provide launchpad bug ID.

Comment: @guiverc, I haven't reported a bug yet, because I don't know what caused it (OS/nix/other package) and have to little knowledge of linux internals to find out on my own..

Comment: Sound works again as of today. I have no idea why..

Answer (score 1):

This made it work again for me when I had similar symptoms (in manjaro):

```
mv ~/.pulse/client.conf ~/.pulse/client.conf.old
killall pulseaudio
pulseaudio --start --log-level=4  # or logging out and in should work as well
```

and waiting for a few seconds.

I had (and am still having) issues due to jack audio though, not because of nix, so this might not work for you.